# Exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8, timepicker

I am getting this message:

"**Exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code**"

This problem occurs when my TimePicker dont have any time choosen when I leave it empty.

My code for the TimePicker looks like this;

```
DateTime break1S = (DateTime)startBreak1.Value;
```

Its on this row i am getting the message but if i set a time for the picker i dont get an message.

Any ideas?

**

Comment: Is `startBreak1.Value;` not already a `DateTime`?

Comment: startBreak1 is a TimePicker.

Comment: Yes, you've mentioned, but what `type` is `startBreak1.Value`?

Comment: Why are you casting it at all then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `startBreak1.Value` is a string :

```
if (startBreak1!= null) 
    DateTime.TryParse(startBreak1.Value, out break1S);
```

if it's a `Nullable<DateTime>` (and I think it is)

```
DateTime break1S = startBreak1.HasValue 
                          ? startBreak1.Value
                          : new DateTime()//or anything you want;
```

or accept that `break1S` can be nullable :

```
var break1S = startBreak1;
```

Comment: I have noticed that i dont need to have no value. I can just set the value to 00:00 but how do i do this with code,

Comment: aaaaand loop to the other question he posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898119/set-timepicker-value-in-code?noredirect=1#comment24394678_16898119)

Answer (score 2):

The solution look like this:

```
DateTime break1S = startBreak1.Value.HasValue ? startBreak1.Value.Value : DateTime.MinValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
DateTime break1S = startBreak1.Value.HasValue ? startBreak1.Value.Value : DateTime.MinValue;
```

Comment: you just copied what i wrote