# Set timepicker value in code

Tags: datetime, windows-phone-8, c#-2.0, timepicker

Is it possible to set the timepicker value in code.

What I am thinking here is that if I have a timepicker and choose a time value, thats the time is should use.

But if I dont choose a time value, it should set 00:00 as default and I want to do this with code.

Hade some crazy idea that looked like this:

```
DateTime date;
date.Hour(00:00:00)
```

Didnt work that good so is there any good way for making this.

**UPDATE**

Here is what i am thinking:

```
DateTime? temp = (DateTime)startDate.Value;
            DateTime date1;
            if (temp == null)
            {
               //Set the time to 00:00
            }
            else
            {
                date1 = (DateTime)temp;
            }
```

**update2**
Here is all code and getting an exception and thats why i want to set the value in code becasue accepting nullable datetime didnt seem to work.

```
  DateTime date = (DateTime)datePicker.Value;
  DateTime break1S = (DateTime)startBreak1.Value;
   _nestedDateStartBreak1 = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, break1S.Hour, break1S.Minute, 0);
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: check my other post about this exception here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893855/exception-of-type-system-invalidoperationexception-occurred-in-mscorlib-ni-dll

Comment: is it not ok to have two post about almost the same thing

Comment: It's okay, just disorganized.  Had i known you had a seperate post it would have helped formulate a better answer.  I commented on the other post to help direct people to this post if they are also confused.  Will take a closer look later.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already overridden the `DateTimePicker` control to be only a `TimePicker` you just need to set the `text` property of the control.

```
    myTimePicker.Text = "00:00:00";
```

If you still have a `DateTimePicker` and want to make it only a `TimePicker` just set the following properties:

```
    myTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
    myTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

My suggestion is to set the default `Text` value ahead of time so that if the user does not input a time, it will contain the default time you specify already.

EDIT:  Setting default value for your `DateTime` object.

```
    DateTime defaultDate = new DateTime(); 
    defaultDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2013-12-31 00:00:00"); //Or whatever you want your default value to be...
    if (startDate.Value == null) 
    { 
        startDate.Value = defaultDate; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        //do something else with the value 
    }
```

Somthing like that should get you the results you want.

Comment: Format and Text or DateTimePickerFormat, I cant set non of these

Comment: In your OP, you said you have a `timePicker` control.  I don't see any code related to that in your example.  Are you asking about a `DateTimePicker` control?  Or a `DateTime` object?

Comment: Okay, the code you posted is not a `DateTimePicker` but rather a `DateTime`.  `Format` and `Text` are methods on a `DateTimePicker`.  So i think you are just trying to manipulate the wrong object.  Take a look at `startDate.Text`.  And don't cast it to datetime.

Comment: I added code that is more specifically aimed at your question.

Comment: I am using it like this:
_nestedDateStartBreak1 = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date1.Hour, date1.Minute, 0); so i need it to be datetime i gues

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31122/discussion-between-alexander-mogren-and-evan-lewis)

Comment: @AlexanderMogren I waited in chat for over an hour (while continuing with my work of course) ;)  But you did not answer, so I updated my code with a more concise way to default your picker value.

Comment: i am really sorry. didnt see you.

Comment: only need to set the time because the date is set from a datepicker

Comment: Sort of feels like you want me to write the code for you... I think with the info I've given you should be able to get it working.

Comment: no i dont want you to write it. i am not sure that you understand what i want. so bad on explain.

Comment: If you are trying to ONLY set a time on a `DateTime` object, then it will be problematic.  Check out the post here on the topic [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037283/how-do-i-represent-a-time-only-value-in-net)  Otherwise, yes I apparently do not understand what you are asking.   Perhaps clarify your question in the OP.